# Add an html element inside the html generated by Contact Form 7

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

We are using Contact Form 7 plugin and would like to introduce an additional element ( italics (i)) inside the html code generated by Contact Form 7.

**Contact Form 7 short tag:**

```
[checkbox* areas_checkbox id:ftype_box class:checkbox use_label_element "Option1" "Option2" "Option3"]
```

**HTML generated by CF7:**

```html
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="areas_checkbox[]" value="Xero">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Option1</span>
</label>
</span>
...
```

For styling reasons why need to add the element italics (i) before the options - Option 1, Option2 etc spans so it would look like this:

**HTML generated by CF7:**

```html
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="areas_checkbox[]" value="Xero">
<i></i>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Option1</span>
</label>
</span>
...
```

Is this possible through jquery or through CF7 shortcode (php)?

Comment: The smarter way to ask the question would be "how do I get this result". Because it might very well be that the extra element is NOT needed. However, it's perfectly possible to add this element via javascript, yes.

Comment: There was a complex css script written about the i/i element - was easier to try and find a way how to add those elements than migrating the css to the new elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `before()` to insert `<i></i>` before `span`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //$( "i" ).insertBefore( $( ".wpcf7-list-item-label" ) );
  $('.wpcf7-list-item-label').before('<i></i>');
})
```

```css
i{border:1px solid red; display:inline-block; height:10px; width:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="areas_checkbox[]" value="Xero">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Option1</span>
</label>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks - had to use jQuery(document).ready(function($) { but it worked